# Turbo C++ Result not coming ok with long int

Tags: c++

I am facing issue with result output with `long int`. Here Below is my Program, I am calculating tax with various methods 1) taking result output in `int` and `long` variable. I think all the four results in my code should be the same, but result output in `tax3` variable is coming different (less by 1) than other three. please help me to understand the reason.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    long salary;
    cout << "Enter Salary: " << endl;
    cin>>salary;
    float tax1, tax2;
    long tax3, tax4;
    tax1 = salary*0.15;
    tax2 = (salary*15)/100;
    tax3 = salary*0.15;
    tax4 = (salary*15)/100;
    cout << "tax1=" << tax1 << endl;
    cout << "tax2=" << tax2 << endl;
    cout << "tax3=" << tax3 << endl;
    cout << "tax4=" << tax4 << endl;
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please, please, do yourself a favor and stop using TurboC++.  It is 25+ years old and isn't even C++98 compliant.  There are many free modern compilers you can use like gcc, clang or even MSVS.

Comment: Why do you think operation on integers should be the same as operation on floats?

Comment: Integer division and floating point conversion/promotion will result in weirdness. Just make your variables `float`s if that's what they're are.

Comment: If you convert a floating point number to an integer it is truncated, not rounded. If you need rounding you must apply that yourself.

Comment: Hint: when you have to spin up a DOS emulator to run your C++ toolchain, it is _too old to be useful any more_.

Comment: @NathanOliver Try 30+!

Comment: Don't use floating-point for money. You introduce errors for no gain. Count in whole pennies (or whole tenths of pennies) instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major types of numbers which are known by the compiler - floating points and Integers. The floating points follows [IEEE-754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers) for representation for 32 bit(float) and 64 bit(double). In turbo C the int is only 16 bits. Also when you copy from float to int only integer part is copied. i.e. consider the following example :

```
     float a=9.8;
     int b=(int)a;
```

In above code when you print b it will give only 9. Also a piece of advice for you, if you want to learn c++ better then please switch from turbo c to gcc.

Comment: Hey Ravinder thanks for your response, But still i didn't find my answer. In above example I am not doing any type conversion. Even a simple input of 100, don't you think result should be same. Unable to understand the different result at third output i.e "tax3"

Comment: @Ishaan while calculating tax3 you are multiplying with 0.15 its floating point. Please see google for type conversion while doing any operation. You can also refer to Dennis rechie c language. Its preety good explained there. And yes c and c++ have implementation for type conversion.